# Pass user input array to method and return an integer?

Tags: java

How can I pass the users input to a method then have that method return an integer or double? I keep getting an error that I have to return an integer but I do not understand how.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Q7_8 {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 10 integers:");
        int[] a = new int[10];

        for(int i =0; i < a.length; i++){
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        average(a);
    }
    public static int average(int [] array){
        int sum =0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            sum += array[i];
            int finalAvr = array[i] /10;
        }
    }
    public static double average(double [] array){
        int sum =0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            sum += array[i];
            double finalAvr = array[i] /10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for your first method simply `return sum;` after the for loop. also, don't forget to store the returned value or print it to console if that's your intent. for your second method change the `sum` variable type to `double` and again `return sum`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
       public static void main(String [] args){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter 10 integers:");
            int[] a = new int[10];

            for(int i =0; i < a.length; i++){
                a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            double avg = average(a); //if average return something, then you must assign the value return somwhere.
            System.out.println(avg); // print the valued return - avg
        }
        public static int average(int [] array){
            int sum =0;
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                sum += array[i];
            }
            return (int)(sum/array.length); //must return if you specify return type
        }
        public static double average(double [] array){
            double sum =0;
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                sum += array[i];
            }
            return sum/array.length; //must return if you specify return type
        }
```

References:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: `Average` method for integer will return wrong value, and `average` for double will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned I'm more of a C++ guy, but it still should be similar:

```
public static int average(int [] array){
    int sum =0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        sum += array[i];
        int finalAvr = array[i] /10;
    }
    return sum / 10; // you need to return the average you calculated
}
```

Same thing with the double's average. you are missing this line:

```
return sum / 10.0;
```